# Use NumberFormat.getCurrency in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I need call this

```
{private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();}
```

in Android Application, but I using Kotlin and I don't know how to do that in Kotlin. How can I do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use as follows:

```
private val currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be performed via:

```
val currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks to answer.

Answer (score 3):

use below method it will return currency format of the current default format locale:

```
 fun currencyFormat() : NumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting way to call currencyFormat.

Comment: @DerekRibeiro Thanks , actually I have extracted this line in method ,that  can be used within scope as per App's requirement.